Trouble with flight school and the change in flight instructors
How do I easily adjust to the instrucuting processess of a new flight instructor, So I can fininsh flight school early enough, I have had 3 flight instructors in the past 2 months and it has stalled my progress.

In what way are you having trouble or not adjusting?

Can you be more specific on what the actual problem is? While methods may vary a bit, your flight school should have a pretty much standardized curriculum, to which the instructors must adhere.

Understandable, every flight instructor has their own whacko view of flight dynamics, so it can be hard to switch once you have have figured out how to placate the one that you are working with.  I had an Embry-Riddle graduate flight instructor tell me that the plane would lose more altitude in a stall when flying downwind vs upwind.

This is more a life coaching request than an answerable question. I'd recommend you take your concerns to the chief pilot. There are simply too many variables in play for internet randos to be able to truly help you out here...

I often have new instructors approach a trainnig exercise that has been half way completed using a different apprroach, making pre flight and post flight brief very strenious.

Some instructors can be overcontrolling (and some moderators too).
I would focus on the curriculum of what you need to learn at school to gain sufficient proficiency to graduate, and to be a safe pilot.
It is difficult to change instructor sometimes, as communication is so important to work together.
But being aware and expressing your needs and feeling the instructor is addressing them is critical.
If you get stuck with someone who goes up with the attitude like:  OK, I'm just getting hours, just do what I tell you, consider switching again.
Although it is very important, in the early stages of training, to listen, as one progresses and starts to feel like they want to fly the plane, then a good instructor knows how to pass the reins to you and let you (safely) do it.
Landing on your own, and soloing, are milestones that we all achieve as pilots in command.
What ever style you instructors have, eventually you take charge of the aircraft.
Having multiple instructors can give you an advantage as they may present different points of view, and getting used to different co-pilots can be an improvement in skills as well.
